# Rabbitmq is consuming RAM

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, celerybeat

Rabbitmq is consuming RAM
[image]
But when I checked, there is 0 in queue and 4 connections. I also tried the following:

- rabbitmqctl stop_app
- rabbitmqctl reset
- rabbitmqctl start_app

Then restarted the rabbitmq-server, celery, and celerybeat services. But the processes still persist to be there.

And I executed 'pkill beam.smp' but multiple processes are still running.

How do I clear them?